# jQuery check if id's has string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of id's in the following format:

```
<div id="#663333+#663300"></div>
<div id="#ffffff"></div>
<div id="#000000+#cccccc+#202020"></div>
```

Let's say I have this string `#cccccc` and I want to remove the ID with this string inside of it. How can I achieve this?

My question is, do I need regex for this or is there some other function already suitable for this purpose. If so how can I remove the ID with this string or another one?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use attribute contains selector. and `.remove()` for removing element:

```
 $("[id*='#cccccc']").remove()
```

or for removing ID:

```
 $("[id*='#cccccc']").removeAttr("id")
```

Comment: Can I add a variable instead of the string inside the attribute contains selector?

Comment: absolutely...`$("[id*='"+your_variable_name+"']").removeAttr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have special characters in the ID, you need to escape it

```
$('#\\#ffffff').remove()
```